# How can I put the three dots showing on what page you are on my views?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, uipagecontrol

I have UIViewControler with three views and UISwipeGestureRecogniser and I can't figure out how to put the dots that indicate on what page you are (like on the home screen on iOS.)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I suggest you take a moment to [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: If the answers have helped you, you should select one by clicking on the checkmark next to the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the [UIPageControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Just so you know, you have to update this control as your user changes from "page" to "page". It's essentially a passive display. (You can't, for example, tell it to automatically update when a  scroll view scrolls.)

Answer (score 2):

You want to checkout the [UIPageControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html)